# Take photograph with camera from UIViewController (MonoTouch)

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, mono, xamarin.ios

What I'd like to do is have a camera embedded into an iPhone view with a button to take photographs (or something simlar to that).

I can't find any controls which do this so I'm a bit lost as to how I'd go about doing this :-\

Comment: Why don't you just overlay a UIViewController over the UIImagePickerController using cameraOverlay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) is the iOS control for taking pictures.